# Using ts-node with ESM module: ipfs-http-client

Tags: commonjs, ts-node, ipfs-http-client

I am trying to run some tests on files I created which use `ipfs-http-client`.
I write code with `typescript` and I am using `ts-node` to run files without actually doing the build (when i do tests). I am running this code in a commonJs folder. As `ipfs` packages is `ESM` only, it gives me an error each time i try to run this code

`No "exports" main defined in .....` (points to the ipfs folder in node_modules)

To reproduce the issue I created a bare [project](https://github.com/giacomogagliano/ipfs-ts-node-issue) which shows exactly what is happening.

I run `npm init` and `npm i ipfs-http-client`.
I have already installed ts-node.

the packages.json file looks like this

```json
{
  "name": "import_esm_in_commonjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ipfs-http-client": "^59.0.0"
  }
}
```

and, for tsConfig file, I am just using the basic ts-node one:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "cwd": "/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/_issues_stack_over_flow/import_ESM_in_commonJS",
    "projectSearchDir": "/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/_issues_stack_over_flow/import_ESM_in_commonJS"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2021"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "./.ts-node"
  }
}
```

I just created an `index.ts` file in the root of the project which looks like this:

```js
import "ipfs-http-client"
console.log("file works");
```

when I run `ts-node index.ts` I receive the previously mentioned error:

`No "exports" main defined in .....` (pointing to the ipfs folder in the node_modules)

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found how to do it.

In order to be able to import `esm` only modules in a typescripy project with `"type": "commonJs"`in the `package.json` like this:

```js
import { create } from "ipfs-http-client";
console.log(create);
```

I did the following:

- explicitly set tsconfig file for ts-node:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "cwd": "/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/_issues_stack_over_flow/import_ESM_in_commonJS",
    "projectSearchDir": "/Users/WAW/Documents/Projects/_issues_stack_over_flow/import_ESM_in_commonJS"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2021"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "./.ts-node"
  }
}
```

- set `"module": "ES2022"` and `"modeResolution": "Node"` in the tsconfig.json in the tsconfig.json

```json
{
...

  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
...
}
```

- when calling `ts-node` use the `--esm` flag:

```bash
ts-node --esm name_of_the_file
```

and it works =)

ps: I also updated the [repo](https://github.com/giacomogagliano/ipfs-ts-node-issue)